# How to add a dependency for an array that is shuffled?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, if-statement, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that shuffles the values in an array. These values represent people who are available. When they are not available, they are removed from the array. I am looking to make this array "dynamic" in that it adjusts the range based on the number of values in the sheet.

I've tried creating a named range but this doesn't eliminate the manual task of changing the named range size. Removing a person from the array will cause the blank cell to be shuffled in with the other values. I've tried experimenting with the .filter() function but I am fairly amateur when it comes to JS and apps script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss =     SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test Sheet");
  var candidates = ss.getRange("Test Sheet!B2:B10").getValues();
  var arrayValues = ss.getRange("Test Sheet!F1:F12").getValues();


  for (var x = 0; x < arrayValues.length; x++) {
    var range = ss.getRange(1, 6, 12);
    var array = range.getValues();                          
    shuffleArray(array);
    range.setValues(array);
  } 
}
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
  }
}
```

Either making the range dynamic or ignoring the blank cells in the array is my goal.

Comment: Can I ask you about ``ignorings the blank cells in the array``? If the value from the range is ``["a", "b", "", "c", "d"]`` and ``["", "b", "", "c", "d"]``, for example, do you want ``["b", "d", "a", "c", ""]`` and ``["b", "d", "c", "", ""]``, respectively?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike ! In the case of ["a", "b", " ", "c", "d"] , the desired result would be a randomization of ["a", "b", "c", "d"] with the blank omitted from the shuffle.  These values represent people who will be "available". The blank in the array is essentially someone who has just been moved to the "unavailable" column of a Google Sheet. I hope that helps to clarify my goal here!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood what you want to do, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more information? For example, those are a sample Spreadsheet and the input and output you want. I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to randomize the cells of "F1:F12" from `var range = ss.getRange(1, 6, 12)`.
- For example, if the value of "F1:F12" is `["a", "b", " ", "c", "d"]`, you want to do this like `["b", "a", "d", "c"]`.

  - You want to remove the empty cells.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? I think that in your situation, the method of `randomize()` can be used.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ss.getRange("Sheet1!F1:F12").randomize();
}
```

#### Reference:

- [randomize()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#randomize)

Comment: Thanks so much Tanaike! This worked perfectly. This may be due to my general lack of experience with programming / JS / GAS. My understanding from your solution is that my function includes the blank values because they were included in the range I defined as an _array_ whereas your function sends null cells to the bottom of the _range_ ? Thanks again for your help and apologies for my lack of knowledge re: formatting and best practices.

Comment: @Softserve Then you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. It seems that the method of ``randomize()`` put the last element when the empty cells are found. I think that this is the specification. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Yes! Thank you for your help!